# Open url on launch in phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I want to open a website url when someone clicks the app icons i.e opens the app.

I tried something like this but no luck.

```
    <script src="cordova.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.open("http://mywebsite.com");
    }

    </script>

</head>


  <body onload="onLoad()"></body>
```

Any help ?

Comment: Hi. Can you tell me why I am getting a black screen after the splash screen on android only when I use the above function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the whitelist to allow your app to navigate to that site.

You can do it by adding this line to your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://mywebsite.com" />
```

or this one if you want to allow the navigation to all the urls on yourdomain.com

```
<allow-navigation href="http://mywebsite.com/*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Load your website to the app using Jquery load() or by Ajax or by InApp browser.

If you want to show your website to a div, you can do it by load() or by ajax call

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Load"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="ajax"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
/*Using Jquery Load()*/
$('#Load').load('http://apache.org');

/*Using ajax*/
$.ajax({
  dataType:'html',
  url:'http://apache.org',
  success:function(data) {
    $('#ajax').html($(data).children());   
  }
});
```

OR by [Inapp browser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)

```
//using device ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
  window.open('http://apache.org','_self');
}

//simple code 
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_self');
```

Before using inappbrowser you must install the plugin to your project To add inappbrowser to project by commanline

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```